# How do I diagnose random long response time issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My heroku app occasionally experiences long run times, on the order of 8 seconds (which is the trigger point to recieve email warnings about long response times).  I originally assumed the issue was related to dyno sleeping, but our new production environment has redundant dynos, and shouldn't sleep.

The issue doesn't occur on any specific route -- even a route as simple as the 'ping' route used by the front-end to keep a session alive can produce it.  I don't think it changes anything, but the latest example occured in an 'options' request -- and the followup request didn't experience any delay at all.

How can I further diagnose this issue?  I've examined the logs around the request in question, there were few log entries in that time period, most chatter from the POSTGRES DB that -- if I'm reading it right -- was saying that it was up, running, and had no connections currently running code.  For some reason, the request just... randomly... took forever.

Comment: Heroku has known performance issues. http://news.genius.com/James-somers-herokus-ugly-secret-annotated

This may very well be part of their issues.

Comment: Unless I'm missing a critical component somewhere, that particular article doesn't apply.  This issue is about the length of time it took the app to return a response after the dyno began processing it, that article is about a time 'gap' caused by bad routing.  Not the same.

Comment: Have you trying to detect the issue using new-relic adons, or log-entrie

Comment: @lombardo Logentries is how I became aware of the issue.  I'll have to examine the new-relic logs more closely next time it happens, see if they have anything of use.